# mp4 video on iOS app using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, mp4

I've been looking at other posted questions regarding playing videos from websites and none of the solutions have worked for me. I get a black screen when I test my app, and the video doesn't seem to ever load.

Globally, I have declared:

```
var moviePlayer:MPMoviePlayerController!
```

And within my ViewDidLoad() function, I have:

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string:"http://uapi-f1.picovico.com/v2.1/v/nMirP/ArwenUndomiel.mp4")!
    self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
    if let player = self.moviePlayer {
        player.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        player.view.sizeToFit()
        player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.None
        player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming
        self.view.addSubview(player.view)
        player.play()

    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am guessing you know that URL redirects to localhost? Can you post a link to the video - it may be a video format issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm not very tech savvy, so let me explain: I used Picovico's APIs to create the video that is linked above through my app. Now, I am trying to embed that video into one of my View Controllers so that the user can see the video they created. This url is in the format that is described in Picovico's documentation to get access to the video. Is it possible to use this url?

Comment: how did you solve this??i am still stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL that Picovico have given you actually responds with a message telling the requester that the content is not at this location but that they should try a different location - this is a common technique for URL redirecting.

You can see this if you try the link in a browser and capture the network request and responses. For example using the link you include above in Chrome gives this response:

[image]

You can see that the server is telling the client (browser in this case) to redirect (i.e. send a new request) to an S3 amazon URL which is where your video actually has been stored by Picovico.

When the browser then sends it's request to that location it finds the video successfully:

[image]

Looking at your video using ffprobe the format seems fine so it seems likely that the iOS client is having a hard time handling the redirect, or else that there was an issues with the URL redirection temporarily on Picovico's servers. If you still have the problem now then the former is most likely the problem.

If you take a look here you can see how someone has solved the problem of iOS media player handling redirects:

- [iOS Mediaplayer and URL redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9062338/334402)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! I noticed that it would redirect before but for some reason did not think it would be a problem. I can actually make a GET request to the site and the response body contains the url where the video is actually stored. Thanks again!